# Laravel DD api doesn't show full array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, api, laravel-5

I am currently in the process of requesting information from an API. When I try to decode the response of json with `json_decode()` it doesn't give me the right data. When I use `var_dump()` it does. How can I make my code correctly display the API data?

I have tried looking on the internet. I have used `var_dump()` with succes yet it doesn't show the information right as with the `dd()`.

```
 $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        if ($err) {
            echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
            $json = json_decode($response);
        }
```

This is the code I use to access the API data. This is the response with var_dump($json):

```
Example: array(344) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1148 (1) {
    ["product"]=>
    object(stdClass)#1141 (3) {
      ["information"]=>
      object(stdClass)#1140 (1) {
        ["deliveryDays"]=>
        string(2) "10"
      }
      ["attributes"]=>
      array(6) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#1142 (2) {
          ["attribute"]=>
          string(18) "Type of sunglasses"
          ["value"]=>
          string(5) "basic"
        }
        [1]=>
        object(stdClass)#1143 (2) {
          ["attribute"]=>
          string(15) "variantid (mcp)"
          ["value"]=>
          string(9) "P105675W1"
        }
        [2]=>
        object(stdClass)#1144 (2) {
          ["attribute"]=>
          string(11) "color (mcp)"
          ["value"]=>
          string(17) "Solid Black/White"
        }
        [3]=>
        object(stdClass)#1145 (2) {
          ["attribute"]=>
          string(8) "quantity"
          ["value"]=>
          string(3) "100"
        }
        [4]=>
        object(stdClass)#1146 (2) {
          ["attribute"]=>
          string(16) "printing process"
          ["value"]=>
          string(12) "tampon print"
        }
        [5]=>
        object(stdClass)#1147 (2) {
          ["attribute"]=>
          string(13) "delivery type"
          ["value"]=>
          string(6) "normal"
        }
      }
      ["price"]=>
      float(213.3)
    }
  }
```

When I use `dd($json)`:

```
  +"product": {#1150 ▼
      +"information": {#1149 ▶}
      +"attributes": array:6 [▼
        0 => {#1151 …2}
        1 => {#1152 …2}
        2 => {#1153 …2}
        3 => {#1154 …2}
        4 => {#1155 …2}
        5 => {#1156 …2}
      ]
      +"price": 407.7
    }
```

As you can see, the API shows ...2 in array 6 but it should show a value. What is wrong about my code?

I want the API to dd the data correctly and show me the data in the api

Answer (score 0):

There is too much data to display for `dd()`, it is limiting results to save your browser and keep speeds higher.

This is because `dd()` is using CSS & JS to display data nicely, if a lot of data would be rendered your browser would eventually not be able to handle this.

If you want to see the results of the first item you will have to dd that exact item you want to view for example:

```
$json->product->attributes{0}
```